# Ethereum Goerli Not sync

Tags: synchronization, fork, ethereum

Ethereum Goerli network has stopped to sync.

I have 2 services:

1. Ethereum Goerli service (execution layer)
2. Teku Service (consensus layer)

Ethereum Goerli Service-logs:

```
INFO [09-17|04:13:32.343] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=29.392ms  number=7,382,818 hash=aa32c4..48c7cc age=1mo1w6h  ignored=182
INFO [09-17|04:13:32.343] Legacy sync reached merge threshold      number=7,382,819 hash=7c38fc..3fd3cd td=10,790,002 ttd=10,790,000
INFO [09-17|04:13:32.363] State sync in progress                   synced=90.24% state=30.90GiB accounts=39,032,106@2.93GiB slots=127,297,641@25.57GiB codes=334,075@2.40GiB eta=1h47m38.796s
WARN [09-17|04:13:32.363] Local chain is post-merge, waiting for beacon client sync switch-over...
```

This has been going on for several days now. Progress 90.24% no change

Teku-service logs:

```
INFO  - Syncing     *** Target slot: 3907886, Head slot: 941050, Remaining slots: 2966836, Connected peers: 12
INFO  - Syncing     *** Target slot: 3907887, Head slot: 941050, Remaining slots: 2966837, Connected peers: 12
INFO  - Syncing     *** Target slot: 3907888, Head slot: 941050, Remaining slots: 2966838, Connected peers: 14
WARN  - Endpoint http://localhost:8546 is INVALID | Still syncing

Invalid remote response: -32601: the method engine_exchangeTransitionConfigurationV1 does not exist/is not available
```

Configuration of services:
Ethereum Goerli:

```
geth --goerli --datadir="/sdb/ethereum/goerli/" --port="30304"  --cache 4096 --http --http.addr="0.0.0.0" --http.port="8546" --http.vhosts="*" --http.corsdomain="*" --http.api="admin, debug, web3, eth, txpool, personal, clique, miner, net" --authrpc.jwtsecret=/tmp/jwtsecret --authrpc.vhosts="*" --authrpc.port=8553 --allow-insecure-unlock
```

Teku-service:

```
~/teku \
  --data-path "/sdb/ethereum/teku" \
  --network goerli \
  --ee-endpoint http://localhost:8546 \
  --ee-jwt-secret-file "/tmp/jwtsecret" \
  --log-destination console \
  --p2p-port=9001 \
  --rest-api-enabled=true   \
  --p2p-discovery-bootnodes "enr:-Iq4QMCTfIMXnow27baRUb35Q8iiFHSIDBJh6hQM5Axohhf4b6Kr_cOCu0htQ5WvVqKvFgY28893DHAg8gnBAXsAVqmGAX53x8JggmlkgnY0gmlwhLKAlv6Jc2VjcDI1NmsxoQK6S-Cii_KmfFdUJL2TANL3ksaKUnNXvTCv1tLwXs0QgIN1ZHCCIyk"
```

How can I fix the problem to sync my Ethereum network?

Answer (score 0):

Any chain node needs Engine JSON-RPC API available it to co-ordinate between consensus layer and execution layer (GoEthereum). Normally the Engine API is exposed over special JSON-RPC endpoint that is called authrpc in GoEthereum. It does JWT token authentication for any request.

Make sure that

- You have authrpc turned on in GoEthereum
- You pass this special endpoint as --execution-endpoint to Lighthouse
  (or similar beacon chain node), as opposite to normal JSON-RPC API
  endpoint
- Both share the same JWT token

Check this for more info:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/135161/ethereum-beacon-chain-node-lighthouse-fails-to-connect-to-goethereum